# blender messes up materials when loading dae

Tags: materials

i've been using blender for a few weeks now to mod beamng files.

all of a sudden, blender started assigning the wrong materials to meshes within the dae. i've checked with multiple dae files. i've also reinstalled blender twice, and have reset the settings to factory, but nothing helps.

can someone please help me?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0):

I run BeamNG - TerryMartinART on YouTube.
I was here looking for answers why I can not import in Johnson Valley terrain block into Blender, its close to a 2 gig DAE. Just stuck loading. No problems with 1024 maps being exported as DAEs and imported in though...

Happened to see your question when looking.
Make sure the meshes you are exporting do not have two UV names. When I bake textures, it will change the name to automap, and the UVmap is also still in there. BeamNG will not accept it and your UVs will be wrong in game. Delete the one that is not being used if that is the case.

Also, if you are trying to export anything from Blender, the only texture you can export is the basic color map. No procedual textures, those have to be baked into color maps, normals, roughness, ao. For example, you find a shinny new material in Blender Kit and put it on a model and export as is. Not going to work.

Also, every time you export a mesh, a dae, export it into its own folder if it is a track mesh/object. The game will write that first main.materials.json from the one color map from Blender. But seems to have problems exporting multiple things after the fact. Those you would have to manually add. However, you can have a mesh that has multiple textures, it will handle that. For car modding, something I do very little of, I just manually add the textures through notepad++.

Also never name a texture with a number for the first character.
example... 1_new_metal

Never name a mesh with a number after the name of the mesh.
example... New_whatever_you_created1
since it gets confused with the LOD system, where those have to have a_ preceding a number, and those have to be structured in the empties, Base00, Start01. But that is track object stuff. I still would not add any numbers to models for jbeams (the flexbodies) It just asking for trouble I have found.

Also, case sensitive is the textures names..

Something I learned from trial and error, Blenders texture paint does not work if using a DDS texture that is using compression. If you ever mess around with that. Use PNGS.

Hit me up on the channel, People ask stuff all the time in the comments. Though I don't see them all, and I always have a million things going on.

These are just the few things that come to mind.

I never use the texture cooking naming system so no suggestions if you use that texture.color.png for example... I prefer to convert my own in Gimp. I never had luck editing those textures after the fact in the World Editor.

Good luck with Modding, there is much I do not know, got about 2 years experimenting and pretty much learned what I know through trial and error. Was hard to get answers, and nearly as impossible to find info on things.

HavocNG is a great friend who also runs a BeamNG channel. Was the first channel that I found to help back when I got started.

Check out Filman86 channel too, guy has a lot of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing errors importing DAEs, I made a video recently on that, and a work around that sometimes works. Think the root problem is those DAE's were authored in MAX or Maya and use slightly different things for the texture info. The BeamNG folks, use a combination of programs so some of the in house DAE from the content folder will load, some wont without parsing errors.
It is still a royal pain in the a to get the textures on the meshes when they do import. Depending on the model.